# How can I find how many times a word appear when I search for it in a BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree popluated from a text file

When i display the BST it looks like this

```
                            the                                                              
            in                              was                              
    Minnesota              it              --              --              
--      --      --      stomach      --      --      --      --      
  --  --  --  --  --  --  only  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
```

I use this method to search for a word from an array in that search tree, if the word in the array existe on the binary search tree, it will sysout it

```
public boolean contains(String d)
{
            BSTNode p = root;

  // Not contained if specified string is null
  if (d == null)
    return (false);

  // OK if specified string equals our data
  if ((p.data != null) && p.data.equals(d))
    return (true);

  // OK if contained in left tree
  if ((p.left != null) && p.left.contains(d))
    return (true);

  // OK if contained in right tree
  if ((p.right != null) && p.right.contains(d))
    return (true);

  // Otherwise, it's not OK
  return (false);

}
```

contains method in BSTNode class

```
public boolean contains(String item) {
    int comp = item.compareTo(data);
    if(comp  == 0) return true;
    if(comp < 0 && left != null && left.contains(item)) return true;
    if(comp > 0 && right != null && right.contains(item)) return true;
    // no matching node was found
    return false;
}
```

i use it in main like that

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            t = array[i];

            if (btree.contains(array[i]) == true) {
                System.out.println(t);

            }

        }
```

OUTPUT

```
was
in
it
was
the
only
the
the
was
in
in
the
the
the
was
only
the
```

How can i output like that

- only: 2
- was: 4
- it: 1
- in: 3
- the: 7

...

So my undertsanding of the codes is that it check all the words in earch node separatly, instead of searching all the nodes for one word then move to the next word, that way i got this output, please correct me if i am wrong.

hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The less intrusive approach would be, collect the words:

```
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         t = array[i];
         if (btree.contains(array[i])) {
              words.add(t); // <-- collect the words
         }
    }
```

print the word/frequency:

```
new HashSet<>(words).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + ":" + Collections.frequency(words,s)));
```

or, add to the a map directly:

```
   Map<String, Integer> word_count = new HashMap<>();
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
             t = array[i];
             if (btree.contains(array[i])) {
                  word_count.put(s, word_count.getOrDefault(t, 0) + 1);
             }
        } 
   word_count.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ":" + value));
```

A more efficient approach if you know that the string is already on the BST do not search it again. For instance:

```
  Map<String, Integer> word_count = new HashMap<>();
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
             t = array[i];
             if(word_count.contains(t){
                word_count.put(s, word_count.get(t) + 1);
             }
             else if (btree.contains(t)) {
                  word_count.put(s, 0);
             }
        } 
   word_count.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ":" + value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how your BST is setup, but you can first create a HashMap and perform a traversal and update each occurcence.

Take a look at a method like this

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); //initialize this in main or shell function

private void wordOccurrenceTree(TreeNode root) {
   
   //inorder traversal
    
    if (root == null) return;
    wordOccurrenceTree(root.left)
    if(map.containsKey(root.value)){ 
         map.put(root.value, map.get(root.value)+1);
    } else {
         map.put(root.value, 1);
    }
   
    wordOccurrenceTree(root.right);

   //HashMap should be populated with each word and occurrence when method is done recursing


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few things wrong:

1. A BST by definition cannot have duplicates. Every left node must be less than the root; every right node must be greater than the root.
2. By searching through the left side of your tree first. You're somewhat ignoring the benefits of a bst. Currently, for data that is greater than the root, your program will begin searching the left node. Then, your program will search the right most tree of that left node. Only then will it return to the main classes contains and continue searching from the right of the root.

Solution for 1: Wrap your string in a class that contains an integer you can increment if the new string to be added is a duplicate.

Solution for 2: after

```
  // OK if specified string equals our data
  if ((p.data != null) && p.data.equals(d))
    return (true);
```

just

```
return p.contains()
```